# Execute code line by line interactively in console inside `with` block

Tags: python, console, with-statement

When testing things interactively in a console, sometimes I use `with` statements. However, because they increase indentation, the prompt changes from `>>>` to `...` and the execution stops until I return to the lowest indentation. It makes sense for function definitions, because the code isn't actually executed inside the function definition. But then there are loops (first iteration could be executed before the loop is fully described), conditional statements, `try`, `with`...

Is there a way to enable such execution? Or do I have to manually operate on the context manager's interface like so:

```
>>> cm = open("E:/test.txt")
>>> f = cm.__enter__()
>>> f.read()
'contents of the file'
>>> cm.__exit__()
```

Comment: The interactive console doesn't execute any block constructs incrementally. It waits until you return to the top-level indentation so it can compile the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense for the console to execute lines one-by-one inside a `with` statement. Many context managers take care to suppress certain kinds of exceptions that take place inside the `with` block, and many others take care to perform some kind of cleanup action before raising certain kinds of exceptions. `open` is a really good example of this -- if there's some kind of exception that occurs while python is reading the file, using `open` as a context manager will ensure that the file is closed again before python raises the exception.

---

This code:

```
with open("E:/test.txt", "r") as f:
    var = f.read()
```

is [identical](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) in what it achieves to this code:

```
try:
    f = open("E:/test.txt", "r")
    var = f.read()
finally:
    f.close()
```

---

If you're executing code in the interactive console, it would probably be better to use the "old-fashioned" pre-context-manager way of opening and reading files, but without the exception-handling.

---

Good python practice outside of the interactive console:

```
with open("E:/test.txt", "r") as f:
    var = f.read()  # file is automatically closed as the `with` block ends
```

"Old-fashioned" solution for executing code line-by-line in the interactive console (dangerous in an actual script -- no exception handling!):

```
>>> f = open("E:/test.txt", "r")
>>> var = f.read()
>>> f.close()  # Remember to manually close the file, since we're not using a `with` statement!
```

Comment: In the end of the day console interactivity is just convenience: being able to iteratively write the program, perhaps using suggestions/autocompletion to discover possibilities on the go. Likewise `with` is a convenience thanks to which you don't have to close the file manually. So IMHO *"It doesn't really make sense"* applies as well to my question as it does to entire console concept. Let's say I'm learning Python (we all here do) and I want to test how context managers work using console. The way the console works, I can't learn that the way I learned a lot of other things in console.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say that your question didn't make sense — it does! I just meant that "it wouldn't make sense for the interactive console to behave in this way". Apologies if I offended, which wasn't my intention.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not offended at all, all I'm saying is to me it would make sense if the console allowed for that. I wonder if there's some technical limitation that wouldn't allow such possibility in the console, or the console devs just agree with you rather than me or just no one bothered to implement it. Or maybe it indeed is implemented, but I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better for me to say: "it wouldn't be *possible* for the interactive console to behave in this way, as it would undermine the whole concept of a `with` statement to execute code line by line ". It would be the same as executing code in a `try ` block before you've typed out the `except ` block. How can you execute the code in the `try `block before knowing which exceptions need to be ignored, or if there's any cleanup action to do when an exception does occur?

Comment: That's a very good point, I think worthy to be edited in to the answer. The console could just move you to the `except` block once an error happens. Similarly as the console evaluates an `if:` condition and increases the indentation if it succeeds - though I see zero usefulness in that. It would be more useful to evaluate first statements in a loop definition, then run next iterations once you deindent. However in all those cases using console could become less intuitive for little gain, so I find it convincing for the design of the console as it is.

Comment: And the console doesn't know if you want `except` at all. Though one more thing - in case of `with` the `except` is already defined, so in this particular case, again, it would make sense!

Comment: But if python encounters an exception early on in the `with` block, it will skip the rest of the block and move straight to the exception handling that's defined in the context manager's `__exit__` method. The `with` statement is analogous to one big `try/finally` block for multiple lines of code. It is *not* analogous to a series of `try/finally` blocks.

Comment: As you say, you *could* design the interactive console to work differently to normal python, but I think that would just be confusing to most people, personally — consistency is important. And there are easy workarounds to test what's happening interactively on a line-by-line basis, as I demonstrated in my answer.